# Are the classes in Java initialized in stack sequences if they have IS-A relationship?

Tags: java

Let's me explain my question by code example, I have this code:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("In class A constructor");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("In class A static initializer");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static {
        System.out.println("In class B static initializer");
    }

    public B() {
        System.out.println("In class B constructor");
    }
}


public class C extends B {
    public C() {
        System.out.println("In class C constructor");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("In class C static initializer");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new C();
    }
}
```

If we run this code, we will have the console print out:

> In class A static initializer
>
> In class B static initializer
>
> In class C static initializer
>
> In class A constructor
>
> In class B constructor
>
> In class C constructor

As you can see, all the static field in the class is being called first from Class A down to Class B then Class C. And then I read about the [Static Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)

> A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is
> initialized

I know that if we just look into the constructor. When we call `new C()`, we will have a call stack:

"5" `Object()`

"4" `A()` calls `super()`

"3" `B()` calls `super()`

"2" `C()` calls `super()`

"1" `main()` calls `new C()`

So why do all static initializers in Class A, B, C finish first, then the constructors? Does that mean the classes in Java initialized in stack sequences if they have IS-A relationship?

I think my question can be answer through here [Detailed Initialization Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) but I am lost with all the details. Hope someone can explain it to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors run after the instance has been created.

The static initializer for C has to finish before the instance of C is created because:

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.

The static initializer for B has to run before C, and A before B, because:

> Before a class is initialized, its direct superclass must be initialized,

Comment: Thanks, I think you have sum up the reasons why it runs like that.

Comment: @VuAnh Note that the quotes are from [JLS §12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "stack sequence"; let me see if I can explain how I expect this goes, which is how I think it has to go.

The Java runtime starts executing C.main; in order to do that, it must initialize the C class object (not an instance of C, but the class C).

It goes and gets the C Class and determines, from that, that it must have B before it does anything like execute the C static initializer (the `static { ... }` thing). It goes and gets the B class.

It determines that, before it executes the B static initializer, it needs A, and goes and gets it. Keep in mind that there are things about A that B does not know except that they're contained in A, so it cannot do anything at all with B before the A class is there and initialized.

Having gotten A, it might determine that it needs the Object class object (the language-twisting necessary to talk about the language you're implementing in language runtimes must drive those people NUTS) and to run its static initializer.

Once it has put the Object class in memory and run its static initializer, it is ready to run the static initializers of A, B, and C, in that order. This completes the portion of setting up the C class as far as the stuff we're talking about here. You could call that "stack order"; it's the same as if C had called B, which called A, which called Object, and in fact that may be how it's implemented (or how it might be implemented).

NOW it's ready for the C constructor to make an instance of C, and the same kind of logic applies. It cannot execute a bit of the C constructor until B is constructed, and not a bit of the B constructor until A is constructed, and not a bit of A until Object is constructed. That's why `super()` must be the first thing in a constructor if it's going to be there; if it isn't there, the runtime executes a no-arg constructor on the superclass.

You could say that the static initializers at each level are started, but their first step is to run the static initializers of their superclass, and similarly for constructors. Whether you say the one code is started and then the super code is run, or that the super code is run before the target code, doesn't seem to me to make much difference.

I'm not a Java runtime expert, but these sequences HAVE to be this way. If you alter the static initializer of A, the above sequence dictates when that code has to be run; I don't see any other way it could work.